# Is it possible to force nonprintable Unicode characters to become visible with CSS?

Tags: html, css, unicode, fonts

**Context:** My app has a phone number input field that does not restrict the input characters. That was the easiest way to allow input of `(`, `.`, `-`, which are the only characters that I was expecting users to enter (yes, I know, not best practice ). I noticed that a user entered `(123) 555­0123` -- which was *invalid* for my (naive) logic because it contains a non-printable ["soft hyphen" character (`0x00AD`)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen). If the soft hyphen were made visible, it would look like `(123) 555[0x00AD]0123`.

**Question:** I do realize that I really just need to sanitize my text inputs better. However, I'm curious to know whether it is possible, using only CSS, to **force all non-printable Unicode characters to be visible** in a particular DOM element (such as an input field)? I'm wondering, for example, if there's a specific font I could use that maybe only has the 128-symbol ASCII character set, and shows everything else (as well as all the ASCII control characters) as a box or other "warning" symbol?